# How to count category value of array of List

Tags: list, flutter, dart

let's say I have a list like the example below

```
<Categories>myList = [
Categories(
    nameCategory: 'Book',
    amount: '20'
  ),
Categories(
    nameCategory: 'Book',
    amount: '40'
  ),
Categories(
    nameCategory: 'Food',
    amount: '20'
  ),
Categories(
    nameCategory: 'Food',
    amount: '15'
  ),
];
```

How I can combine the duplicate values of that list and count the value of the list based on name ??
I can combine the list and the count value of the list but that only works just in a general list like sum total

what I want to do is make a new List but only combine several parts that share the same property like the same category or same class like that

this is an example what I want to achieve

```
<Categories> anotherList= [
Categories(
    nameCategory: 'Book',
    amount: '60'
  ),
Categories(
    nameCategory: 'Food',
    amount: '35'
  ),
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would replace your `List<Categories>` with a `Map<String, Categories>`.  Then you can easily look up the `Categories` object given its name and mutate the existing `Categories` object.  For example, something like:

```dart
var mergedCategories = <String, Categories>{};
for (var categories in myList) {
  var name = categories.nameCategory;
  var amount = categories.amount;
  (mergedCategories[name] ??= Categories(nameCategory: name, amount: 0))
      .amount += amount;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially trying to get an aggregate value from a list, which is what `List.fold` is meant to help with.

Here's an example of how you might use it:

```
class Category {
  final String name;
  int amount;
  
  Category({required this.name, required this.amount});
  
  String toString() => "Category(name: $name, amount: $amount)";
}

void main() {
  final categories = [
    Category(
      name: 'Book',
      amount: 20
    ),
    Category(
      name: 'Book',
      amount: 40
    ),
    Category(
      name: 'Food',
      amount: 20
    ),
    Category(
      name: 'Food',
      amount: 15
    ),
  ];
  
  /** 
   * Here is where the aggregation is done
   */
  final List<Category> aggregated = categories.fold([], (list, item) {
    try {
      // Check whether the category is already in the aggregate 
      final existingCategory = list.firstWhere((c) => c.name == item.name);
      
      // Category is already in the list, so just add the amount of the current item.
      existingCategory.amount += item.amount;
      
      return list;
    } catch (_) {
      // The category has not yet been added - so add it here
      list.add(item);
      return list;
    }
  });
  
  print(aggregated);
}
```

I've changed your category class a bit for simplicity, but the principle should be the same. You can read more about the fold function here: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/Iterable/fold.html

Answer (score 0):

A pretty straightforward method is by using the `groupBy` function provided by the *collection.dart* package.

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

groupBy<Categories, String>(list, (c) => c.nameCategory).values.map(
    (list) => list.reduce(
        (a, b) => new Categories(a.nameCategory, a.amount + b.amount)
    )
);
```